# UWP SerialCommunication: await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync Does Not Return SerialDevice

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, serial-communication

Simple bit of code to return Port information:

```
private async void GetPortNames()
{
   string deviceSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();

   DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await 
      DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector);

   List<string> portNamesList = new List<string>();
   foreach (var item in deviceCollection)
   {
     SerialDevice serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(item.Id);
     string portName = serialDevice.PortName;
     portNamesList.Add(portName);
   }
}
```

For whatever reason, the "await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(item.Id)" never returns a SerialDevice. I am running Win10 v.1809 and I have also verified package manifest references Serial Communication.

Here are some other things that I have tried: I created Net Standard 2.0 library with Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility and referenced it into my UWP app.  UWP would not let me use SerialPort.GetPortNames() method.  I also tried to implement the RJCP.IO.  That didn't work either.

Any ideas?

** Update **

This could be an Architectural problem with the Panasonic Toughbook FZ-M1: As I mentioned earlier, "SerialDevice.FromIDAsync(item.Id)" does not return a SerialDevice.  It actually returns null.  The Panasonic's version of item.ID is pointing to the right thing in the registry, but item.Name = "DESKTOP-QR####" (that is the machine name) is returned instead of "COM##".

Comment: By "never returns a SerialDevice" I assume you mean it hangs when you do `await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(item.Id)`?

Comment: When I ran my code snippet through the debugger, it looks like the await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync executes, but the app does not hang.  I can still navigate through my app and do other functions.  Maybe a better description is await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync waits forever? @IanKemp